# @Id of type date for SpringData Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

The data pojo for spring-data-mongodb is configured as follows:

```
@Document(collection="DateKey")
public class DateKey {

@Id 
private Date dateid;
private Date dateval;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
```

The @Id column is a `java.util.Date` field, when the data is saved in mongo-db using spring-data-mongodb, it is getting saved as

> ```
> {
>     "_id" : ObjectId("5a356628d73a971c3c8ab1e7")
> }
> ```

Whenever other datatypes are used, no such behavior is observed. Due to this when we try to find the value from database, it throws the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No 
converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.types.ObjectId] to 
type [java.util.Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

only java.sql.Date is saved as Date in MongoDB, an ordinary java.util.Date is not!
Must provide a custom converter